# If else within function

Tags: r

Reading http://adv-r.had.co.nz/Functional-programming.html I'm attempting to modify a function to update a vector of values where 10 is replaced with 110 and all others are replace with 2.

Here is my code to replace 10 with 110 :

```
replacer <- function(x) {
  x[x == 10] <- 110
  x
}

replacer(c(0, 10))
```

This works as expected and returns `0 110` but how to modify in order to set values to 2 where 10 is not encountered ?

I've tried :

```
replacer <- function(x) {
 if (x[x == 10] <- 110)
  x
 else
  2
}

replacer(c(0, 10))
```

Which returns same result : `0 110` but I'm expecting `2 110`

Update :

Using  Sotos comment solution is :

```
replacer <- function(x) {
    ifelse( x == 10, 110, 2) 
}

replacer(c(0, 10))
```

Comment: `ifelse( x == 10, 110, 2)`

Comment: FYI best not to edit the question with the solution… put that in an answer